# what is difference in content of image object and image raw data

Tags: c++, .net, serialization, udp, c++-cli

I want to send an image over UDP network in small packets of size 1024 bytes.
i have two options.

```
imgBinaryFormatter->Serialize(memStream, objNewImage);        // Sending an image object
                         OR
imgBinaryFormatter->Serialize(memStream, objNewImage->RawData);    // Sending a raw data of image
```

what is difference in their content and when to use ? 
For reference full function is given below

```
Image^ objNewImage = Image::FromFile(fullPath);         // fullpath is full path of an image
MemoryStream^ memStream = gcnew MemoryStream();
Formatters::Binary::BinaryFormatter^ imgBinaryFormatter = gcnew Formatters::Binary::BinaryFormatter();          // Binary formatter
imgBinaryFormatter->Serialize(memStream, objNewImage);    // Or objNewImage->RawData ?? 
arrImgArray = memStream->ToArray();                                                                             // COnvert stream to byte array

int iNoOfPackets = arrImgArray->Length / 1024;
int i;

for (i = 1; i < iNoOfPackets; i++){
socket->SendTo(arrImgArray, 1024*(i-1), 1024, SocketFlags::None, receiversAdd);
}

int remainedBytes = arrImgArray->Length - 1024 * iNoOfPackets;

socket->SendTo(arrImgArray, 1024 * iNoOfPackets, remainedBytes, SocketFlags::None, receiversAdd);
```

If you find improvements in code, feel free to edit code with suitable solution for memory constraint application.

Comment: Ooo hungarian. What is the type of objNewImage? In general, serializing everything along side the raw data will get you the metadata (width, height, wotnot), raw data will be slightly smaller and more easily processed by things like a GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use

the [Image.Save Method (Stream, ImageFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) for serialization into a `Stream`

and

the [Image.FromStream Method (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx) for deserialization from a `Stream`

*or one of their overloads*